# ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From tests/integration/genres.test.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am currently enrolled in a course from Code with Mosh of node.js. I am currently on the integration tests module. Below is my code

Getting the below error

● api/genres › GET/ › should return all the genres

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From tests/integration/genres.test.js.

```
const request = require('supertest');

let server;

describe('api/genres', () => {
        beforeEach(() => { server = require('../../app'); });
        afterEach(async() => { await server.close(); });

    describe('GET/', () => {
        it('should return all the genres', async () => {
           const res = await request(server).get('api/genres'); 
           expect(res.status).toBe(200); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `server = require('../../app')` supposed to do? `require` will return the same thing every time is called

Comment: It is so that when I make changes to the code jest is going to rerun the code and the above server will still be occupied since the port is occupied